# How can I get my Ionic 4 Typescript paths to work?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I am in the process of upgrading my Ionic 3 app to Ionic 4 with Typescript 3.1, but I'm running into trouble with the Typescript paths.

I have the following in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
    "@models": [ "src/models/index" ],
    "@services": [ "src/services/index" ],
    "@shared": [ "src/shared/index" ],
    "@app/*": [ "src/app/*" ],
    "@models/*": [ "src/models/*" ],
    "@services/*": [ "src/services/*" ],
    "@shared/*": [ "src/shared/*" ]
},
```

and this in my `src/tsconfig.app.json`:

```
"paths": {
    "@models": [ "models/index" ],
    "@services": [ "services/index" ],
    "@shared": [ "shared/index" ],
    "@app/*": [ "app/*" ],
    "@models/*": [ "models/*" ],
    "@services/*": [ "services/*" ],
    "@shared/*": [ "shared/*" ]
},
```

Visual Studio detects the files just fine and doesn't give me any kind of errors, but when I run `ionic serve`, it can't find any of these files.  I get errors such as:

```
[ng] src/models/jobs/job.model.ts(1,33): error TS2307: 
    Cannot find module '@models/customers/customer.model'.
```

for the line:

```
import { ICustomerModel } from "@models/customers/customer.model";
```

How can I get `ionic serve` to honor my Typescript paths?

Comment: In my case, there was no need to edit `tsconfig.app.json`. That might be an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I needed to add

```
"baseUrl": ".",
```

to the compilerOptions.  After I added this, it worked.

Full `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@models": [ "models/index" ],
            "@services": [ "services/index" ],
            "@shared": [ "shared/index" ],
            "@app/*": [ "app/*" ],
            "@models/*": [ "models/*" ],
            "@services/*": [ "services/*" ],
            "@shared/*": [ "shared/*" ]
        },
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "module": "es6",
        "types": [ "node" ]
    },
    "exclude": []
}
```